# GitHub Actions composite steps not grouping output properly

Tags: github-actions

I am using several composite steps in my GitHub Actions workflows. For some reason, they are showing the "raw" output like this:

```
##[group***Checking out the ref
[command***/usr/bin/git checkout --progress --force -B deployment-manager refs/remotes/origin/deployment-manager
Switched to a new branch 'deployment-manager'
branch 'deployment-manager' set up to track 'origin/deployment-manager'.
##[endgroup***
[command***/usr/bin/git log -1 --format='%H'
'15db9b52614501f2212043fffa9b6df86c047892'
##[group***Run actions/setup-java@v3
```

Why are the group/endgroup/command decorators not working correctly to format the output?

*Edit*
Here's a minimal workflow to reproduce the issue:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: riskalyze/build-actions/ecr-build-push@v2
      with:
        ecr-lifecycle-policy: ${{ secrets.ECR_LIFECYCLE_POLICY }}
        ecr-repo-policy: ${{ secrets.ECR_REPO_POLICY }}
        path: .
        shared-account-id: 123123123123
        shared-role-arn: arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/githubActionsEcrRole
```

This is the composite action being used: https://github.com/riskalyze/build-actions/blob/main/ecr-build-push/action.yml

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducer

Comment: @rethab I edited and added a workflow to reproduce the issue.